# probability of an event given two overlapping distributions?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

Given that a mean count of ants on a peony is 25 with standard deviation 47 and mean count of ants on a rose is 58 with standard deviation 97, how do we calculate the probability that the total ant count on 50 flowers is greater than 900?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: What are the 50 flowers (25 & 25, 49 & 1, something else)? Do you want the probability the sum is *exactly* 900, *at least* 900, 900 +/- 50, something else?

Comment: its not from a text book although its similar in style to a problem that is. information about the 50 flowers is not given.

Comment: Where is it from? What do you mean that "information about the 50 flowers is not given"? You should probably add the tag & follow the procedures outlined in the wiki anyway. Note that if we don't have any information about the distribution of flowers, the question is not answerable.

Comment: " Note that if we don't have any information about the distribution of flowers, the question is not answerable". Thank you. you've just answered my question.

Comment: OK, I'll add that as an official answer.

Answer (score 3):

If we don't have any information about the distribution of flowers, the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 3):

While the question doesn't supply all the needed information (and so gung's answer is correct), we can outline approaches that we could use if we had some more information -- it is likely to be be intended to work in one of only a few ways.

First: I assume that the standard deviations in the question refer to the number of ants not the distribution of the mean count.

Second: I presume we're supposed to assume independence of ant counts across flowers, irrespective of species.

Third: I presume we're meant to assume the total ant count can be approximated by a normal distribution.

Then here's some discussion of what would be involved for the two cases I think are most likely what's being asked about:

1. If we had fixed counts of flowers -- $n_r$ roses and $50-n_r$ peonies, then the distribution of total ant-count would be based on the convolutions of the individual random variables, but using  the basic properties of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation#Properties) and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) combined with the normal assumption I mentioned before, we can derive a normal approximation to the total count of ants.
2. Let's assume we have a random sample of 50 flowers, with some fixed probability, $p_r$ of each one being a rose and $1-p_r$ of being a peony. This is a [finite mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) with two components, which for a single flower we can [calculate a mean and variance for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Moments), and then add 50 of those using a similar approach to that in 1.

[I haven't actually given the calculations for the specific case here because it reads like a self-study question, if somewhat unclearly worded, but at least that's an outline of how to do it under those two plausible sets of assumptions about what's intended.]